# Update a value in a table based on a value in another table

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

Is it possible to update a value in a table based on a value in another table in Oracle?

I am trying to accomplish something like this(I know that this is not a proper UPDATE statement):

```
  UPDATE table1 
   SET table1.flag = 1 
  FROM table1 t1 
 INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id 
 INNER JOIN table3 t3
   ON t2.company = t3.company
 WHERE t1.emp_id = '5632'
   AND l2.company = '83CP'
   AND t1.code = 'LIEU'
```

Comment: @Ben This is not a duplicate.  In that question they would like to update the field with  a value in another table.  I would like to update based on a value in another table (as part of the condition)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate Azzi, all the solutions proposed in the answers will work exactly the same way. It doesn't matter if you're setting a "flag" or using a column to update. I would use the MERGE option, as I find it easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Ben The question is different; whether or not the answer is the same.

Comment: You're arguing over whether updating a column with the value of another column or a constant is the same or not? I'm the only person who's voted to close so far and you can ignore me entirely, however, whatever answer you get will be _identical_ save for it won't be `update set a.column = b.column` but `update set a.column = 1`. If you don't agree that these are identical then that's your perogative; I would, however, hope that you would be able to apply the code to your own query. If you can't you might want to consider updating your answer with the problems you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have a primary key in table1 so use it instead of rowid but if you haven't use

```
update table1
set flag =1
where rowid in ( select t1.rowid
                 FROM table1 t1 
                      INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id 
                 INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.company = t3.company
                 WHERE t1.emp_id = '5632'
                       AND l2.company = '83CP'
                       AND t1.code = 'LIEU'              
               )
```